# Left join values with where condition, multiple problems on missing entries

Tags: sql

I thought i can get this Problem out with a simple left join, but it doesnt work.

Data:

```
Table 1        
**VALUE**
X23
FG21.21
:
GT31+
```

To get the resolved data from that values i have to left join an other table. The Problem is, that ':' and 'GT31+' are wrong. There dont exist in Table2 and nothing will be resolved, but they have to be in the output.

```
Table 2
**VALUE     DATE         NAME**
X23      '1992-02-01'    YELLOW
X23      '2999-12-31'    BLUE
FG21.21  '2005-12-08'    BLACK
FG21.21  '2999-12-31'    RED
:         **NO ENTRY IN THE TABLE!**
GT31+     **NO ENTRY IN THE TABLE!** 



SELECT a.VALUE as VAL, b.VALUE as VAL_B, b.NAME as NAME
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b on (a.value = b.value)
WHERE DATE = '2999-12-31'
```

My output is:

```
VAL       VAL_B      NAME
X23       X23        BLUE
FG21.21   FG21.21    RED
```

My desired output is

```
    VAL       VAL_B      NAME
    X23       X23        BLUE
    FG21.21   FG21.21    RED
    :         null       null
    GT31+     null       null
```

Comment: When several tables are involved, it's good programming practice to qualify all columns. E.g. `b.date` instead of just `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  `where` condition turn your  `left join` into an `inner join` because it filters on a column in `table2`.

Just put the condition directly in the `join`

```
SELECT a.VALUE as VAL, b.VALUE as VAL_B, b.NAME as NAME
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.value = b.value
                  AND b.DATE = '2999-12-31'
```

Comment: That was realy quick. You are right, thanks for your explanation. I will accept the answer when "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes" is over.

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition on the second table to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.VALUE as VAL, b.VALUE as VAL_B, b.NAME as NAME
FROM TABLE1 a LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 b 
     ON a.value = b.value AND b.DATE = '2999-12-31'
```

Also, qualify all column references so it is clear where the columns are coming from.